# Remove roleClaims at one Query shot asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, role-manager

I am using asp.net core **RoleManager** to perform roleClaim(permission) based authorization. The below code work fine but it take too much time execute because i delete the roleclaim each at a time. but i want to delete roleclaims(permission) at one shot delete query , Can anyone help me ? thank's in advance.

//my controller code

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> SaveRolePermission([FromBody] RoleClaimVM model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.RoleId) || model.ClaimValues.Length <= 0) return Json(new { status = false });
                var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(model.RoleId);
                if (role == null) return null;
                var roleClaims = _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role).Result.ToList();
                if (roleClaims.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var item in roleClaims)
                    {
                        await _roleManager.RemoveClaimAsync(role, item);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var item in model.ClaimValues)
                {
                    await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(role, new Claim(CustomClaimtypes.Permission, item.ToLower()));
                }
                return Json(new { status = true });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Json(new { status = false });
            }
        }
```